# How to manually remove preload fonts settings in Wordpress?

Tags: fonts

We had some plugin installed that preloads fonts.
We do no use the plug in anymore but in the console we have errors like this (see also the screenshot):

> GET ../wp-content/themes/fonts/libre-franklin-v7-latin-800.woff2
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

This is probably caused by the preload plugin.
We do not remember the name of the plugin since we have tried out several.

Question is: how can we manually remove traces of this plugin (and others)?
[image]

Comment: I'd first try with some generic optimization plugin, such as WP-Optimize: it can potentially remove all traces of uninstalled plugins, even those which do not show up as errors, but which might anyway slow down your site. Search for "Wordpress Optimization Plugin", and choose the one which fits best for you. For more expert answers, you might also want to ask this question on the wordpress.org community.

Comment: @1NN Thank you. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared the errors derrived from the WP Dashboard -> Appearance -> Theme Editor -> Theme Files -> Stylesheet
Entries were made there. Removving these entries and installing plugin OMGF solved the issue.